# Error with using userform as an argument in case statements

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a few userforms that have comboboxes that I load with a selection of years. Depending on the userform, the list of years changes. There is a good amount of logic on how the list is constructed.  I have therefore create a separate subprocedure for it that would utilize the userform in the logic. I have this in the calling procedure in the userform Initialize event:

```
Set ufName = ufTest
Call Load_Year_Comboboxes(ufName)
```

And in the procedure, I have this:

```
Sub Load_Year_Comboboxes(ufName As Object)

    Dim rFirstYear As Range
    Dim yCount As Integer, X As Integer, iThisYear As Integer, iYearCount as integer

    Select Case ufName
        Case(ufTest)
            yCount = 0
            Set rFirstYear = wsUserInput.Range("F10")
            Do While yCount < iYearCount
                ufName.cboBeginYear.AddItem rFirstYear.Offset(yCount, 0)
                yCount = yCount + 1
            Loop
        End Select
    'do other things
End sub
```

My problem is that I get an error with the Select Case. I get the 450 error "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". I have tried with the variable defined as a userform and MSForms.Userforn, but still with no luck.  I read on another post that it had to be assigned as an object. I cannot find any posts as to this specific scenario.

Comment: One way would be to `Select Case ufName.Name` and then check `Case "Name of Form"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, you can't check the passed Object this way.  Here are 3 ways you could use to check which Object was passed:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Load_Year_Comboboxes(ufName As Object)
    'check the name property
    Select Case ufName.Name
        Case "UserForm1"
           MsgBox "UserForm1 is being processed"
    End Select
    
    'check the type with Select
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf ufName Is UserForm1
           MsgBox "UserForm1 is being processed"
    End Select
    
    'check the type with If
    If TypeOf ufName Is UserForm1 Then
        MsgBox "UserForm1 is being processed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. With the first example, I get “Object does not support property or method”.  And indeed .Name is not in the intellitype options. However, the 2nd example does indeed work, and presumably the 3rd.

Comment: If you are passing in a UserForm then there should be a Name property.  But obviously, if the passed object doesn't have a Name property that would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way you are trying to pass the userform.  I'm not sure that you can pass it quite the way that you are trying (maybe someone else knows the answer to that); however, this worked for me.

in the userform I added this to the `UserForm_Initialize` event

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Load_Year_Comboboxes (Me.Name)
    End Sub
```

and then in a standard code module

```
Sub Load_Year_Comboboxes(ByVal ufName As String)

    Dim rFirstYear As Range
    Dim yCount As Integer, X As Integer, iThisYear As Integer, iYearCount As Integer

    Select Case ufName
        Case "UserForm1"
            yCount = 0
            Set rFirstYear = wsUserInput.Range("F10")
            Do While yCount < iYearCount
                ufName.cboBox1.AddItem rFirstYear.Offset(yCount, 0)
                yCount = yCount + 1
            Loop
        End Select
    'do other things
End Sub
```